# Android: Issuing search method too frequently causing crashes

Tags: android

I have a search bar, a search button (as i just converted to using onKeyPress and haven't removed it yet), and a TextView.

It works well, except that each key press issues a new call to Search(), and the old call doesn't stop running. If i type too quickly or for too long, the app crashes. How do I better manage my threads or quit prior Search() executions when onKeyPress() fires?

Thanks!

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="corp.dtc.tel" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/tel_ico"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TEL_Main_Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_box"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Here"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search..."
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:onClick="Search"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:hint="List of Numbers will be here"
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:maxLines="50"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:freezesText="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package corp.dtc.tel;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;


public class TEL_Main_Activity extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView textView;
EditText editText;
Button button;
Employee[] list;
Employee[] employees;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setLogo(R.mipmap.tel_ico);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    LoadArray la = new LoadArray();
        try {
            employees = la.LoadArray(this, R.raw.droid);
        } catch (IOException e) {}

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tel_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    textView.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Search(findViewById(R.id.layout));
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        //check if any view exists on current view
        Button style = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), TEL_Main_Activity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tel_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void UpdateTextView () {
    textView.setText(String.format("%-20s %10s %10s", list[0].name, list[0].number, list[0].support));
    for (int x = 1 ; x < list.length & list[x] != null ; x++) {
        textView.append("\n" +
        (String.format("%-20s %12s %10s", list[x].name, list[x].number, list[x].support)));
    }
}

public void Search(View view) {
    textView.setText(null);
    EditText line = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    String[] tokens = line.getText().toString().split(" ");
    if (tokens.length == 0)
    {
        //There was nothing in the search box.
    }

    else {
        list = new Employee[50];
        int listCtr = 0; //Keeps ctr for list[]

        for (int dbCtr = 0 ; dbCtr < 5000 ; dbCtr++) {
            System.out.println(dbCtr);

            if (listCtr == 50)
                break;

            if (employees[dbCtr] == null)
            {
                //Should have less than 50 listed items and finished searching.
                //Now it is okay to update the list view.
                UpdateTextView();
                break;
            }

            if (employees[dbCtr].contains(tokens))
            {
                list[listCtr] = employees[dbCtr];
                listCtr++;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The App purpose: search through company employee listing, display results.(Must have less than 51 results to display)

Comment: The apps purpose: Search through company employee listing, display results. Must have less than 51 results to display. (Large Company)

Comment: can we see the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that "the other search doesn't stop running" is really a good description of what's going wrong here.  I don't see any "threads."  I think that the problem is that you're attempting to do the search "**on** keyPress," therefore "with **every** keyPress."

A much better way to think of what you're trying to do here would be:  *"I want to automatically 'push the button' as soon as the user stops typing."*

So, basically, when the user starts pressing keys, you'll start a timer (if such a timer isn't already running) set to go off in, say, 1/2-second.  Then, in any case, you'll set a flag to `true` which indicates that "the user has recently pressed a key."

When the timer goes off, it checks to see if this flag is `true`.  If so, it sets the flag to `false` and reschedules the timer to go-off again in another 1/2-second.  Otherwise, it does what "pressing the button" used to do, then it will reset the (separate) flag that indicates that the timer is running.

As long as the user is pressing at least one key every 1/2 second, the timer will continue to reschedule itself (and, no one else will attempt to start the timer since they can see that the timer's running).  Eventually, though, the timer will see that the key-has-been-pressed flag has *remained* false for half-a-second.  That's when it "presses the button," causing the search to take place.

For a thorough solution, the timer-routine, after performing the search, would check the "key-has-been-pressed" flag once again.  If it's *still* `false`, then the user really has stopped typing and it's time to present those search-results.  Otherwise, the timer-routine should start rescheduling itself again.

Eventually, the user **will** stop typing.  The timer will run the search, and, having done so, will see that the user still hasn't typed anything more.  Results will then be displayed (for the first time).